# Scanning Diametric codes using socket programming

Tags: sockets

I am new to socket programming. How can I read the QR codes in c++ socket programming using a scanner? I am using recv() function to read the data buffer from connected socket. But when i print it on console using puts() i am getting "NoRead" Is there any other function I can use to read QR code?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `read()` as I've used to read data from image sources, give it a try